# Angular 6 - autocomplete always turn to off?

Tags: angular, forms, autocomplete

In angular 6 i'm creating a simple reactive form.
The relevant markup looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="login">E-mail cim</label>
            <input autocomplete='email' formControlName="login" type="login" id="login" class="form-control" pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$"
             name="login">
        </div>
```

It's sets the autocomplete to "email".
In the browser i got this message:
`[DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes (suggested: autocomplete='email', confirm at ...)`

If i look at the generated html, there is autocomplete='off'.

Why it is turning to autocomplete="off" and don't keep the email value?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in stackblitz? I'm using Angular 6 already, and this is not happening in my templates.

Answer (score 0):

autocomplete attribute for input tag isn't an angular thing, it's an HTML5 attribute and it expects a value of either "on" or "off". If you assign a value the attribute doesn't expect(ie not "on" or "off") then it will default to "off